# Loop find last modified file with a specific name inside a folder

Tags: vba, loops, file

Here is my problem, on my excel sheet I put paths of every folder that I want to check

```
V:\Folder1\
V:\Folder2\
```

Inside those folder I want vba to give me the name of the last modified file based on a specific name.

I will give an example:

In my folder1 I have those files :

```
Lo_2021_1
Lo_Full_2021_1
Lo_2021_2
Lo_Full_2021_2
...
Lo_2021_50
Lo_Full_2021_50
```

In my folder2 I have those files :

```
Li_2021_1
Li_Full_2021_1
Li_2021_2
Li_Full_2021_2
...
Li_2021_50
Li_Full_2021_50
```

I want vba to give me the name of the last modified file that starts with `Lo_2021` in my folder1 and `Li_2021` in my folder2 (so I don't want `Lo_Full` and `Li_Full`)

I already created a code that gave me the name of the last modified files but they are `Lo_Full_2021_50` and `Li_Full_2021_50` whereas I want `Lo_2021_50` and `Li_2021_50`

Here is my code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub name_last_file()

Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
Dim objFile As File
Dim myFolder
Dim strFilename As String
Dim dteFile As Date
Dim list_path As Range
Dim path_ As Range
Dim myDir As String

Set list_path = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))


For Each path_ In list_path
    myDir = path_.Value
    
   'set up filesys objects
    Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
    Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)
    
    'loop through each file and get date last modified. If largest date then store Filename
    dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
    
    For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
        If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
            dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
            strFilename = objFile.Name
            
    End If
    Next objFile
    MsgBox strFilename
    
Next path_

End Sub
```

This will give me `Lo_Full_2021_50` and `Li_Full_2021_50` whereas I want `Lo_2021_50` and `Li_2021_50`.

Is there a way to say that I want the last modified file that start with `Lo_2021` or `Li_2020` so that I will get `Lo_2021_50` and `Li_2021_50` as a result ?

I'm really thankful for your help

Comment: Your code does not filter in any way the names of the examined files. You should use, in fact, I will post an updated code to return what (I understood) you need...

Comment: I am surprised your code compiles at all! What does `path_.values` give you? Do you mean `path_.Value`? Please try to copy and paste your code rather than type it (or portions of it).

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for that. Yes I mean path.Value, I have edited the code by pasting it. Thanks for your remark

Answer (score 1):

Please, test the next updated code:

```
Sub Give_name_files()
 Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject, objFile As File, myFolder As oobject
 Dim strFilename As String, dteFile As Date, list_path As Range, path_ As Range
 Dim strRoot As String

 strRoot = "Lo_2021" 'the beginning of the tested files name

 'First I Select paths that are on my excel cells
 Set list_path = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

 For Each path_ In list_path
    myDir = path_.Value

    'Set up filesys objects
    Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
    Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)

    'loop through each file and get date last modified. If largest date then store Filename
    dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)

    For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
        If left(objFile.Name, Len(strRoot)) = strRoot Then
            If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
               dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
               strFilename = objFile.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next objFile
    MsgBox strFilename
 Next path_
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help but there is still one problem to solve. Here we take strRoot = "Lo_2021" which is in my Folder1 (V:\Folder1\) and I also have to look at "Li_2021" which is in my Folder2 (V:\Folder2\) . This is the main issue because I thought about creating a loop but it will give 4 case which are : Lo_2021_50 and Blank for Folder1 and Blank and Li_2021_50 for Folder2